# i dont understand how to return a string value from boolean

Tags: java, mysql, string, type-conversion, boolean

i want to To hold the seating plan of the theater hall, use a one-dimensional array of type boolean,seatArray.
Initialize all the elements to false to indicate that all the seats are empty. do this so when a guy makes reservation to a spesific seating i should use boolean to determine if its empty or taken i dont know how to do this.
Please help. i only need help about the boolean part (and its display)

Thank you guys so much in advance
the question is this :

You are a computer engineer working in the IT department of Biletix, a company of online reservation. You
are asked to develop a new application to assign seats on the Stüdyo Sahne (capacity: 12 seats). Your
application asks for the following operations:
1 View SeatPlan
2 Make Reservation
3 View Reservation
4 Exit

this is an example of the output
Welcome!!! Please select
1 View SeatPlan
2 Make Reservation
3 View Reservation
4 Exit
Operation: 2
1st Row (Price 100 TL)
2nd Row (Price 50 TL)
3nd Row (Price 25 TL)
Select Row & Seat: 3 1
Name: selen
Row3/Seat1 is reserved.
1 View SeatPlan
2 Make Reservation
3 View Reservation
4 Exit
Operation: 2
1st Row (Price 100 TL)
2nd Row (Price 50 TL)
3nd Row (Price 25 TL)
Select Row & Seat: 1 4
Name: elif
Row1/Seat4 is reserved.
1 View SeatPlan
2 Make Reservation
3 View Reservation
4 Exit
Operation: 1
Row1 1-- 2-- 3-- 4-X
Row2 1-- 2-- 3-- 4--
Row3 1-X 2-- 3-- 4--
1 View SeatPlan
2 Make Reservation
3 View Reservation
4 Exit
Operation: 2
1st Row (Price 100 TL)
2nd Row (Price 50 TL)
3nd Row (Price 25 TL)
Select Row & Seat: 1 2
Name: Ali
Row1/Seat2 is reserved.
1 View SeatPlan
2 Make Reservation
3 View Reservation
4 Exit
Operation: 1
Row1 1-- 2-X 3-- 4-X
Row2 1-- 2-- 3-- 4--
Row3 1-X 2-- 3-- 4--
1 View SeatPlan
2 Make Reservation
3 View Reservation
4 Exit
Operation: 3
Enter Name:ELIF
Reservation Details:
Name:ELIF
Row1/Seat4
1 View SeatPlan
2 Make Reservation
3 View Reservation
4 Exit
Operation: 4
Exit...
Thank you guys so much in advance

Comment: Sorry to say but your question formatting is very poor.

Comment: Use `<br>` for new lines. This is difficult to read.

Comment: @javafan  i edited please can you help me now?

Comment: @EJoshuaS i edited please can you help me now?

Comment: @CemKoçak i think the theater hall will be a 2D object then why do you want to do it in 1D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you a little bit because it is very unclear what you are asking .

Lets assume that the theater is of 3 rows by 4 columns i.e. of 12 seats a boolean value of false indicate seat is free and true indicates that it is reserved.

```
//first init the hall

boolean seats[][]=new boolean[3][4];
//now set all seats to false indicating unreserved
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
 for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
  seats[i][j]=false;

// now lets imagine that you booked the seat at 2nd row and 1 column 
//to reflect this just do this

  seats[1][0]=true;

//now if you want to display which all seats are empty just loop through the //array

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
     {
       if(seats[i][j]==false)
           // do some code to handle seat empty

      else
         // do some code to do seat reserved

}
```

Its quite obvious you will use variables for booked seats and number of rows and columns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and so sorry for the late reply and the fact that you had to endure reading that horrible question. I was new to coding and was really confused at mandatory java class for engineers.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what you're trying to ask.

To return a string based on a booleans value there are lots of ways, the easiest:

```
boolean bol;
String str;

if(bol==true) {
str="first string option";
}

else {
str="second string option";
}

return str;
```

Obviously that must be inside a String method.

Comment: Yes its difficult to say what he is asking.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and so sorry for the late reply and the fact that you had to endure reading that horrible question. I was new to coding and was really confused at mandatory java class for engineers.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a method which returns String according to a boolean. Like that:

```
public String methodName(boolean b){
    String str="";
    if(b==true)
        str="Boolean is True";
    else
        str="Boolean is False";
return str;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and so sorry for the late reply and the fact that you had to endure reading that horrible question. I was new to coding and was really confused at mandatory java class for engineers.